# What is AngularJS best practice regarding "$" dollar sign prefixes for private isolated scope properties?

Tags: angularjs

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api) seems to discourage it.  But angularstrap, for example, uses "$" as a prefix for the private properties of isolated scopes within directives.  I have been using underscores "_" for this purpose but want to hear what the angular communinity says about it.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the AngularUI code was written (or started being written) before the angular claimed all of those $-prefixed attributes.

I tend to use _ for truly private stuff (like _internalSaveRepresentation() or _privateVariable), and put a $ prefix on functions that are on objects a user could reasonably be expected to add attributes to, for the same reason. So, DataModel.$save() or .$id (which indirects to either _id or id or whatever the user set in _idAttribute). That way, if there's a DataModel that references a save attribute (maybe the state of the 'save' checkbox or something), it doesn't accidentally overwrite the $save() method.

The important thing is not declaring modules that have a $name (like $route or $location) at the injector-global level, rather than hanging attributes off of your service objects that have $ on them.